# How do I calculate the volume of purchased and sold vehicles separately?

Tags: pine-script

I want to calculate and plot the volume of purchased and sold vehicles separately from each other.There is a sample code I am trying to write for this.But I am encountering an input error.Does anyone know what I should do?

```
//@version=5
indicator("received-sold volume")
Received_volume=received_price*received_amount
Sold_ volume=sold_price*sold_amount
Plot(Received_volume,color=color.green)
Plot(Sold_volume,color=color.red)
```

Comment: There's a public script available that does what you want. See (Up/Down Volume by mks17)[https://www.tradingview.com/script/BKXRcpZD/]

Comment: What I want to do is to create the volume line of the vehicles bought and the volume line of the vehicles sold.

Comment: That is, I want to show the volume of purchases made in one bar of a tool (b) on a one-minute chart as a separate volume line and the volume of sales made as a separate volume line.

Comment: TradingView doesn't provide bought/sold volume separately. You have to calculate it yourself like in the indicator I mentioned.

Comment: I asked because I couldn't calculate.

Comment: Scroll down in the link I provided. That shows the code.

Comment: The one you mentioned was more like average